# Laravel morphedByMany where condition and count

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables: Posts and Pages that share one table for tags (morphToMany).

My tables and relations:

Table: Tags
id, name

```
public function posts()
{
return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'taggable');
}
public function pages()
{
return $this->morphedByMany('App\Page', 'taggable');
}
```

Table: Posts
id, name, active

```
public function tags()
{
return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
}
```

Table: Pages
id, name, active

```
public function tags()
{
return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
}
```

**How can I get all tags and count from both tables where pages.active and posts.active**

I tried this query but this query returns only tags that are in both models:

```
Tag::whereHas("posts", function($q) {

$q->where("posts.active", "=", 1);

})->whereHas("pages", function($q) {

$q->where("pages.active", "=", 1);

})->get();
```

I need a query that can return tag if exists in one of the models but where active = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it

```
$tags = Tag::where( function( $query ){
        $query->whereHas('posts', function ( $subquery ){
            $subquery->where('active', 1 );
        })
        ->orWhereHas('pages',function ( $subquery ){
            $subquery->where('active', 1 );
        });
      })->withCount('posts','pages')->get();
```

Comment: thnx bro your legend. i use like this: Tag Name - ((($tag-
>posts_count+$tag->pages_count) ? is there a way to sum both counts from query or Iam doing it right?

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.